# How to relabel a reiser4 partition in Debian?

Tags: debian, reiserfs

On Jessie the only tools available are:

```
/sbin/mkreiser4
/sbin/mkfs.reiser4
/sbin/fsck.reiser4
/sbin/debugfs.reiser4
/sbin/measurefs.reiser4
```

No one looks like useful to rename the label without reformatting the partition.
Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reiserfstune -l NEW_LABEL /dev/sdXy
```